# angular service injection is not consistent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am beginner in AngularJS

I have an angular service as below

```
angular.module('TestModule', []).service('testservice', ['$timeout', testservice]);
function testservice($timeout) {
    /* my function */
}
```

I am injecting this module in my main module as below in app.js

```
angular.module("MainModule", ['TestModule']);
```

and trying to inject the testservice in my controller as below

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
.module('MainModule')
.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$state', 'testservice',  testController]); 
function testController($scope, $state, testservice ) {
/*I have my functions here */
}

})();
```

Sometimes, it gets injected successfully and in sometimes it throws error as below

> Unknown provider: testserviceProvider <- testservice <- testController

I cannot guess out the problem and I stuck completely with it. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible from the code you've posted. Please, provide a plunk or a fiddle that can replicate this error.

Comment: actually, this simple thing is working as expected, but if i merge the same kind of things in a large application, it is not consistent

Comment: It may be related to some promises from $timeout not handled properly.

Comment: A fiddle will be very helpful for observers to understand your problem.

Comment: Then something stays behind the scenes. As it was said, code above alone can't cause this error. This can happen if you accidentally override a module like `angular.module('TestModule', [])` (without `testservice` service`).

Comment: @estus: thats correct buddy... accidently overriden... if you want, put this as an answer and I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above can't cause this error

> Unknown provider: testserviceProvider <- testservice <- testController

This can happen if `TestModule` that contains `testservice` becomes accidentally overriden with another definition of `TestModule`:

```
angular.module('TestModule', []);
```

If the error appears and disappears randomly, this means that in some cases file that contains `TestModule` module with `testservice` is loaded before file that contains overridden `TestModule`, and in some cases it's not.

Comment: the problem was  I was creating services in new js files and every time i was using     `angular.module('TestModule', []);`
which overrides the previous service and only the last service is available in the `TestModule`